# Spivak, Ch. 25, "Complex Numbers": Why would a set $P$ of "positive" complex numbers have to contain both $1$ and $-1$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I am trying to follow the theory part of Chapter 25, "Complex Numbers", of Spivak's *Calculus*. At some point he says

> Unlike P1-P9, the rules P10-P12 do not have analogues: it is easy to
> prove that there is no set $P$ of complex numbers such that P10-P12
> are satisfied for all complex numbers. In fact, if there were, then
> $P$ would have to contain $1$ (since $1=1^2$) and also $-1$ (since
> $-1=i^2$), and this would contradict P10.

P1-P9 are properties of "(real) numbers" as defined in the very first chapter of the book. It is straightforward to prove that they are true of complex numbers.

P10 is the Trichotomy law

> For every number $a$, one and only one of the following holds
>
> (i) $a=0$
>
> (ii) $a$ is in collection $P$
>
> (iii) $-a$ is in collection
> $P$
>
> $P$ is the collection of all positive numbers

My question is: why would a $P$ for complex numbers have to contain $1$ and $-1$? Ie, I did not understand the explanation in the first snippet above.

Comment: if $x>0$ then $x^2>0$, and if $x<0$ then $x^2>0$, so either way $x^2\in P$; in particular, $1=(1)^2$ and $-1=(i)^2$ are both in $P$

Comment: Either $i$ is a positive number, or $(-i)$ is a positive number.  If $x$ is a positive number, then so is $(x)^2$.  So, regardless of whether $i$ or $(-i)$ is positive, since $(i^2) = -1 = [(-i)^2]$, you have that $-1$ is a positive number, which implies that $1 = (-1)^2$ is a positive number.  Then, both $1$ and $-1$ are positive, which leads to the contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You also need [P12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037234/inequalities-proofs-in-spivaks-calculus): (Closure under multiplication) If $a$ and $b$ are in $p$, then $a \cdot b$ is in $P$.

Using P10 and P12, you can prove that if $a \neq 0$ then $a^2$ is in $P$:

By P12, if $a$ is in $P$ then $a^2$ is in $P$. But by P10, if some nonzero $a$ is not in $P$ then $(-a)$ is in $P$, and so $(-a)^2=a^2$ is in $P$. So $a^2$ is in $P$ regardless of $a$.

Spivak is saying that in the complex numbers, both $1$ and $-1$ are nonzero perfect squares, so they would both have to be positive if the positivity axioms are to be satisfied. But this violates P10.

Comment: It's just so strange. Up to this point in the book, the symbol $-1$ represents the additive inverse of the real number $1$. Now, $1$ is in $P$, so $-1$ is not in $P$ (of real numbers). But now in this chapter 25 about Complex Numbers, apparently $-1$ is not the same as before. It is actually the complex number $(0,1)\cdot (0,1)=i^2$. This is not the same as the $-1$ from before, correct?

Comment: @evianpring: in any field $-1$ is the additive inverse of $1$. $-a$ is the notation for additive inverse of $a$. Further note that complex number $a+i0$ (or $(a, 0)$) is not same as real number $a$ but rather the subset of $\mathbb{C} $ consisting of numbers like $a+i0$ is isomorphic to set of reals as far as field operations are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a set $P\subset \Bbb{C}$ such that P10-P12 hold. Then

- Consider the number $a=1$. We know $1\neq 0$, so by P10, either (i) $a=1\in P$ or (ii) $-a=-1\in P$. In either case, by P12 (closure under multiplication), we have $a^2\in P$. But we obviously have $a^2=1$. Thus, $1\in P$.
- Next, consider $a=i$. Again, $i\neq 0$ so either $i\in P$ or $-i\in P$. In either case by P12, we have $a^2=-1\in P$.

So, $1\in P$ and $-1\in P$, but this is a contradiction to P10.